# Non case sensitive remove row with specific data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this Google Apps Script that is checking specific columns for listed words in it and removes rows that match those words:

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 
  var arrayOfWords = ['möbelübernahme','können übernommen werden','caravan','wohnwagen'] 

  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  
    var row = values[i]; 
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfWords.length; j++) {    
      if (row['21','17'].indexOf(arrayOfWords[j]) > -1) {         
        sheet.deleteRow(i+1);     
        rowsDeleted++;   
        break;         
      }
    } 
  } 
};
```

Can I make the words check to be not case sensitive? So if I include a word like "mietwohnung" it will remove all matching options: MIETWOHNUNG, mietwohnung, Mietwohnung?

Comment: If you google: how to make lowercase a specific value in javascript, you will find that this can be achieved with the [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method. Apply this function to the searching values and compare them against the `arrayOfWords`.

Comment: Also this `row['21','17']` is not supported in javascript.

Comment: well you could go for the budget option and tell spell check "always replace this with this" XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You need to convert each element in the `row` array to lower case. In order to do that, you need to use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). In this way you will apply `toLowerCase` to every element of `row`. The modification will be here:

  ```
  if (row.map(r=>r.toLowerCase()).indexOf(arrayOfWords[j]) > -1)
  ```
- `row['21','17']` is not a valid javascript object. You can't slice an array like that. If your goal is to check only column `21` and `17` then use this if statement instead:

  ```
  if ([row[21],row[17]].map(r=>r.toLowerCase()).indexOf(arrayOfWords[j]) > -1)
  ```

  Note here that `row[21]` is column `V` and `row[17]` is column `R` in the sheet. Remember the index in javascript starts from `0`. Namely, `0` is column `A`, `1` is column `B` etc.

---

### Solution:

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 
  var arrayOfWords = ['möbelübernahme','können übernommen werden','caravan','wohnwagen'] 

  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  
    var row = values[i]; 
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfWords.length; j++) {    
      if (row.map(r=>r.toLowerCase()).indexOf(arrayOfWords[j]) > -1) {         
        sheet.deleteRow(i+1);     
        rowsDeleted++;   
        break;         
      }
    } 
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*An alternative to the solution already provided*

You can simply use `toLowerCase()` - in this way "Mietwohnung" will become "mietwohnung" for example, and the comparison can be made with no issues.

So, you can do the following modification to your script:

```
for (let i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   var row = values[i];
   var found = false;
   for (let k = 0; k < row.length; k++)
      for (let j = 0; j < arrayOfWords.length; j++)
         if (row[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(arrayOfWords[j]) > -1)
            found = true;
   if (found == true) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
      rowsDeleted++;
   }
}
```

The above script loops through all the values from the data range, hence the other loop added, and then making use of the `toLowerCase()` function, checks if the value is part of the `arrayOfWords` array and if needed, deletes the row(s). The `found` variable is used here to indicate whether the word has been found or not.

#### Reference

- [JavaScript String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).